# How to select last NON-NULL values of each column in a Hive partition

Tags: sql, hive, partition, windowing

I have a hive-table containing transactional data of the form (highly simplified)

```
id  Status  Value   UpdatedTimeStamp

515 Open    1   2014-05-08T11:43:27
516 Open    NULL    2014-05-08T11:43:27
515 Answered    1   2014-05-09T11:43:27 
515 Closed  NULL    2014-05-10T11:43:27
517 Open    NULL    2014-05-09T11:43:27
516 Closed  NULL    2014-05-09T11:43:27
```

For my use-case, I need an output table containing unique ids with column entries as the last non-NULL value in that column for that particular id when sorted by timestamp.

Hence, the desired output is:

```
id  Status  Value   UpdatedTimeStamp

515 Closed  1   2014-05-10T11:43:27
516 Closed  NULL    2014-05-09T11:43:27
517 Open    NULL    2014-05-09T11:43:27
```

I am trying to achieve that by using windowing functions on partitions

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE testSample2 SELECT id, FIRST_VALUE (Status) OVER SortedData, FIRST_VALUE (Value IGNORE NULLS) OVER SortedData, FIRST_VALUE (UpdatedTimeStamp) OVER SortedData FROM testSample WINDOW SortedData (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UpdatedTimeStamp DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

This gives me NullPointerException (Probably, IGNORE NULLS is not yet supported in Hive). Please suggest me how to take the last non-NULL value.

Comment: If you are selecting the "last Non-NULL" value with respect to each id, then why are there `NULL` values in your desired result?

Comment: there are NULL values if there is no non-NULL value for a specific queryID

Comment: How is what you are saying different than "The Last Value For Each Id." ?

Comment: If the last value is NULL, then "the Last Value" for that id would be NULL, right? But I want the value to be last NON NULL value. for example, for id=515 , last value for the column "Value" is NULL, but in my updated table, the column "Value" is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
select ss.vl1, FIRST_VALUE(ss.ky) OVER (PARTITION BY ss.vl1 ORDER BY ss.nl, ss.vl rows unbounded preceding) 
FROM (
    SELECT IF(s.vl=123456, 'sasa', 'AAAAAA') as vl1, s.vl, s.ky, IF(s.ky IS NULL, 1, 0) as nl
    FROM (
        select explode(map(NULL, 123, 1, 1234, 2, 12345, 3, 123456)) as (ky, vl) from default.dual) s ) ss;
vl1     _wcol0
AAAAAA  1
AAAAAA  1
AAAAAA  1
sasa    3
```